# Spark scala config for S3 config --request-payer requester

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am writing Spark job to access S3 file in parquet format. The bucket owner has enabled `request-payer` config. I can access the S3 file using below cli command (without request-payer it gives access denied exception)

```
aws s3 ls <s3_path> --request-payer requester
```

How can I set this config in Spark job? I have tried below setting ("fs.s3.useRequesterPaysHeader", "true") but it didn't work and getting access denied exception.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
  .config("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
  .config("fs.s3.useRequesterPaysHeader", "true")
  .appName("Test")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Maybe use `spark.hadoop.` prefix to pass custom settings, as described in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration ?

Comment: s3a doesn't support (nov 2021) requester pays. when it eventually does, know that the configuration option will not be that one

Comment: thanks Stevel, can you point me to source to followup on this, couldn't find anything about s3a on https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/requester-pays-buckets-glue-emr-athena/

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14661

Comment: put differently: s3 is AWS closed source client exclusive to EMR; S3A is the ASF open source one maintained in apache hadoop codebase